# Dúvida sobre o cache em Laravel

Tags: laravel

Já trabalhei com php a alguns anos atrás e utilizava o Code Igniter, nele eu lembro que houve um problema. Quando duas pessoas logavam no site e os seus computadores estavam na mesma rede o sistema acabava retornando os dados uma da outra. Isso foi possível de solucionar, mas no Laravel eu não achei nada sobre. O que encontro é sobre utilização da [cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache) mas não sobre esse assunto. Alguém poderia me indicar algum lugar que falasse sobre isso? Não encontrei nada em específico na documentação.

Comment: Você está falando de quais dados? De Acesso?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ruim. Acredito que sua pergunta não tem co-relação com Laravel, e sim com lógica de programação e proteção do sistema. Pesquise sobre `sessions` e `cookie`.